# Can cable signal strength cause failures in particular layer 3 protocols?

Tags: networking, ipv6, modem, isp, ipv4

In the past, I've lost 98%ish IPv4 connectivity on my Comcast connection, but I *had* IPv6 connectivity fully. (IPv4 SYNs, or the corresponding SYN-ACKs (it's hard to tell) were getting dropped most of the time; if they succeeded, the connection was stable and packet loss was nominal.)¹

Tonight, I've lost *all* IPv6 connectivity. (The opposite issue, essentially.)

In both instances, the support tech decided to run a [level 3 diagnostic](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Diagnostic_mode#Level_3_diagnostic) on my modem, and in both instances, claimed that my signal strength was weak.

In my mind, a copper coax cable, even one with bad signal strength, can not exhibit bias against layer 3 protocols. **Is there something about how cable Internet actually works that can cause single-protocol dropouts, correlating with signal strength, or is Comcast pulling my leg, and this is probably a configuration issue in software somewhere on their end?** In the latter case … is there any way to talk sense to the support agent?

<sub>¹After a tech debugged the physical layer for an entire day to no effect, this issue was resolved by replacing the modem itself.</sub>

Comment: In direct answer to your boldtext/title, no, the wire cannot do such a thing. That said however, Coax carries a multiplexed signal, and hardware+firmware demultiplexes it. Cable channels and internet bandwidth come in on distinct sub-bands within the carrier signal, so what signal strength can do is affect the particular sub-bands. Software and hardware upstream may even make decisions about what to deliver based on real-time assessment of the link. So, there are many potential points of failure, and many at layer1, but none are the cable itself unless it is physically damaged.